# Disable Kaspersky firewall in favor of Comodo Firewall

Tags: firewall, kaspersky, comodo-firewall

I have recently bought and activated my Kaspersky Internet Security, and it conflicts with my Comodo Firewall which was installed before.

I want to disable Kaspersky firewall, but to keep their antivirus. I looked in Control Panel, and it seems like I can only remove the whole product and a "modify" option does not exist.

How can I remove their firewall? Should I remove my Comodo Firewall instead?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to use Kasperky's built-in firewall and disable Comodo Firewall to avoid a conflict between the two firewall applications.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @TheOrthanormalBeginner - Comodo and Kaspersky Internet Security are not compatible. Please see the list of incompatible products here: http://support.kaspersky.com/us/9852#block1

-Kaspersky Lab

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post, ok, I think firewall disable option is there in latest kaspersky atleast.
And also i had to disable web antivirus, otherwise host unreachable error was coming for some sites.
posting this to avoid misinformation about this good anti-virus & firewall combo.

Comment: It's thoughtful of you to post to avoid misinformation, but your answer is hard to understand and it isn't clear what your solution to the question is.  Can you clarify?  Thanks.